# Enabling Filestream - Adding Filegroup filestream doesn't work

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to enable Filestream in my database (i am working on (localdb)\v11.0).

I went to the SQL server configuration manager and enabled the filestream, so far so good then i went to my object explorer and opened the properties of my server and in the Advanced Tab i changed FileStream Access level to full access enabled.

I made a query to add a filegroup for my filestream but i always got the following error :
Msg 5598, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
FILESTREAM feature is not supported on user instances.

this is the query i tried to execute:

```
ALTER DATABASE QuizDatabase ADD
FILEGROUP FileStreamQuizDatabase CONTAINS FILESTREAM;
GO
```

I've no idea what am i doing wrong or if i should enable something else.

thanks in advance

Comment: The error message is *quite* clear in this case - you've got to stop specifying `User Instance` or `AttachDBFileName` in your connection string, and instead attach the database to the server permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Filestreams seem not to be supported in the (VS integrated) Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (which you appear to be using)

according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ceeaf961-fe8e-430a-99b7-c83ff9de77c3/filestream-feature-is-not-supported-on-user-instances?forum=ssdt) (same issue) you have to use an ordinary sql server

Answer (score 2):

LocalDB doesn't support filestream, use SQL Express or full edition.

Here's a feature matrix:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable the File stream at the service level.

1. Go to SQL Server configuration tool folder --> SQL server Configuration manager --> SQL server services --> Your instance.
2. Double-click and navigate to file stream tab.
3. Enable and apply.
4. Restart your instance and you should be good to go.